# Is it possible to push address of self to vector on struct construction?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a struct Box and a vector of pointers to Box objects like so,

```
struct Box {
    int number;
    Box() {
        /* Push address of self to the vector here */
        /* All I need is a way to access the address of self */
    };
};

std::vector<Box*> Boxes;
```

I am trying to make the creation of objects (for GUI elements) easier by pushing the address of the object to a vector when created. That way I can edit the members of the object after creation and not have to manually push to vector.

Is it possible to access the address of self in the object constructor?

Comment: Be careful. You must not use this pointer to call functions until the object is fully constructed. Doing so is UB if the function is virtual (and you don't want to make the assumption that a function will remain non virtual in future versions of the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boxes.push_back(this);` is all you need. Also remember remove it in destructor to avoid use after free.

```
std::vector<Box*> Boxes;

struct Box {
    int number;
    Box() {
        Boxes.push_back(this);
    };
    ~Box() {
        Boxes.erase(std::remove(Boxes.begin(), Boxes.end(), this), Boxes.end());
    }
};
```

Online demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0db13cfdff4a70b